# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ' .d img.displayImage'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax-error

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="flex-item a">
    <p>A</p>
    <img class="displayImage" src="img/image-placeholder.svg" />
    <textarea class="textInput"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="flex-item b">
    <p>B</p>        
    <img class="displayImage" src="img/image-placeholder.svg" />
    <textarea class="textInput"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="flex-item c">
    <p>C</p>        
    <img class="displayImage" src="img/image-placeholder.svg" />
    <textarea class="textInput"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="flex-item d">
    <p>D</p>        
    <img class="displayImage" src="img/image-placeholder.svg" />
    <textarea class="textInput"></textarea>
</div>
```

This is my js:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var imageAreaArray = [];

$.each(arr, function(i, val){
    imageAreaArray.push("document.querySelector('." + val + " img.displayImage')");
});    

$.each(imageAreaArray, function(i, val){
    var contentVal = $("'." + arr[i] + "img.displayImage'").closest('textarea');
    imagePath = $("'." + arr[i] + " img.displayImage'").src;
});
```

This should take the value of the nearest `<textarea>` to the `img.displayImage` in the selected '`<div>`', and also take the `src` of the `img.displayImage`, but I get the following error and I'm not sure how to fix.

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.d img.displayImage'

**UPDATE**

No longer getting the error message, but now `contentVal` and `imagePath` are showing as undefined. Any idea why undefined might be showing?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do as I can guarantee you there's a better way than this.

Comment: I don't know if I can call this spaghetti code, but it's some sort of pasta, and not in a good way.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I'm trying to upload an image and text to an API, but now that I am no longer getting the <uncaught error, unrecognized expression: '.d img.displayImage' , the  `contentVal` and `imagePath` display as undefined. Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have additional single quote in jQuery selector, which is evaluating to a invalid selector like `$("'.a .. ..'")`

```
$.each(imageAreaArray, function(i, val){
    var contentVal = $("'." + arr[i] + "img.displayImage'").closest('textarea');
    //                 ^^
    imagePath = $("'." + arr[i] + " img.displayImage'").src;
    //            ^^
});
```

1. Also `$(..).src` will output undefined. use `$(..)[0].src` or `$(..).prop('src')` to get source.
2. `.closest('..')` return closest parent element. `<textarea>` here is the sibling of `img`. Use `.next('textarea')` instead of `.closest()`

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential problems with your code.  First off, I don't believe that jQuery selectors need to be wrapped in single quotes, so get rid of those.  Secondly, when querying for the closest textarea you missed a space between arr[i] and img.displayImage.

I would suggest caching the jQuery selected element:

```
var element = $(`.${arr[i]} img.displayImage`);
var contentVal = element.closest('textarea');
imagePath = element.src;
```

Notice that the ` characters are `backticks`, typically found at the top-left of English keyboards.  This syntax requires that ES6 string interpolation is supported by the browsers you're targeting.  As an alternative, you can just build the selector by using the same method you're currently employing.

```
var element = $("'." + arr[i] + " img.displayImage'");
...
```

Comment: Thanks @jjbandit. The error is not displaying anymore, but `var element` shows as undefined. Have any idea why this might be happening?